# Can a Python method check if it has been called from within itself?

Tags: python, recursion, introspection, inspect

Let's say I have a Python function `f` and `fhelp`. `fhelp` is designed to call itself recursively. `f` should not be called recursively. Is there a way for `f` to determine if it has been called recursively?

Comment: Well, can't you just not call `f` from `f` ?

Comment: The philosophy of Python is that we are all sensible adults, and as such, read and respect the documentation. Just add a comment to your documentation saying that `f` should not be called recursively. Btw. does `f` take any user-defined functions as input? If not, you as the author of that function should be able to make sure it doesn't call itself recursively.

Comment: @madjar: Recursive calls can be indirect: `f` calls user-supplied function `k` which in turn calls `f` again.

Comment: @Björn Pollex hit the nail on the head. There are many layers of indirection, and I want to ensure that some sub-function doesn't call f.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module for this:

```
>>> import traceback
>>> def f(depth=0):
...     print depth, traceback.print_stack()
...     if depth < 2:
...         f(depth + 1)
...
>>> f()
0  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
 None
1  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
 None
2  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
 None
```

So, if any entry in the stack indicates that the code was called from `f`, the call was (in)directly recursive. The `traceback.extract_stack` method gives you an easy access to this data. The `if len(l[2] ...` statement in the example below simply counts the number of exact matches of the name of the function. To make it even prettier (thanks to agf for the idea), you could make it into a decorator:

```
>>> def norecurse(f):
...     def func(*args, **kwargs):
...         if len([l[2] for l in traceback.extract_stack() if l[2] == f.__name__]) > 0:
...             raise Exception('Recursed')
...         return f(*args, **kwargs)
...     return func
...
>>> @norecurse
... def foo(depth=0):
...     print depth
...     foo(depth + 1)
...
>>> foo()
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in func
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in foo
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in func
Exception: Recursed
```

Comment: This works but not on objects as the function can be called on a same object type but different object in foo, also it would break generally on functions that are named the same. `extract_stack()` gives only limited informations

Answer (score 3):

You could use a flag set by a decorator:

```
def norecurse(func):
    func.called = False
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        if func.called:
            print "Recursion!"
            # func.called = False # if you are going to continue execution
            raise Exception
        func.called = True
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        func.called = False
        return result
    return f
```

Then you can do

```
@norecurse
def f(some, arg, s):
    do_stuff()
```

and if `f` gets called again while it's running, `called` will be `True` and it will raise an exeption.

Comment: This has some unwanted memory: say your `f` is defined as this: `def f(func): print func()`. If you call it with `f(f)`, you will get the recursion warning. If you then call it with `f(lambda: 'foo')`, you will also get the warning, while it didn't recurse...

Comment: This will not work reliably in an application where the function is called from several threads, though I guess it might be adapted to work there too by using [threading.local](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.local) as storage for the boolean.

Comment: @jro I assumed this is for debugging purposes and the OP doesn't want to continue execution if unwanted recursion is detected. If he _does_ want to continue, it's easy enough to add `func.called = False` before `raise`ing.

Comment: @lazyr Why would I possibly assume that the code needed to be thread safe if that wasn't mentioned in the question?

Comment: I did not mean you should have. The comment was meant to caution and advice those who might use this solution in such a case. The `traceback` solution is threadsafe, this one is not, but it can be made so.

Comment: You should probably use `try: result = func(*args, **kwargs) finally: func.called = False` just in case the wrapped function throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved jro's answer to make it work with objects while making it explicitly threadsafe:

```py
import threading

class NoRecurse:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.RLock()
        self.seen = set()

    def __call__(no_recurse, f):

        def func(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with no_recurse.lock:
                if len([l[2] for l in traceback.extract_stack() if l[2] == f.__name__]) > 0 and self in no_recurse.seen:
                    raise Exception('Recursed')

            with no_recurse.lock:
                no_recurse.seen.add(self)

            r = f(self, *args, **kwargs)

            with no_recurse.lock:
                no_recurse.seen.remove(self)

            return r

        return func
```